# chemfig -- How to add horizontal space around an arrow?

Tags: chemfig

Trying to add space around an arrow with `\qquad` leads to an asymmetrical result. This can be prevented with additional braces, but why are they needed?

**1. The resulting image:**

[image]

In the first line, the arrow is close to the left expression.
In the second line, it is about centered.

**2. The code:**

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\newcommand{\Beispiel}{
    \schemestart \chemfig{A-B} \qquad \arrow \qquad \chemfig{A-B} \schemestop
    \vspace{1em}\par
    \schemestart \chemfig{A-B} \qquad {} \arrow \qquad \chemfig{A-B} \schemestop
}

\begin{document}
    \par without debug mode:
    \par
    \Beispiel

    \bigskip
    \par with debug mode:
    \par
    \setchemfig{scheme debug=true}
    \Beispiel
\end{document}
```

The code difference is the additional braces (`{}`) between `\qquad` and `\arrow`.

**3. Questions:**

Why is that?

What would be recommended to add space around an arrow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\newcommand{\Beispiel}{
    \setchemfig{compound sep=15em, arrow offset=6em}
    \schemestart \chemfig{A-B} \arrow \chemfig{A-B} \schemestop
    \setchemfig{compound sep=5em, arrow offset=1em}
}

\begin{document}
    \schemestart \chemfig{A-B} \arrow \chemfig{A-B} \schemestop
    
    \par without debug mode:
    \par
    \Beispiel
    
    \bigskip
    \par with debug mode:
    \par
    \setchemfig{scheme debug=true}
    \Beispiel
    
    \schemestart \chemfig{A-B} \arrow \chemfig{A-B} \schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very helpful. And by enclosing the ```\setchemfig``` expression together with the scheme by braces, I don't change the variables for the rest of the document.

Comment: ```compound sep``` (default: 5 em) seems to equal twice the ```arrow offset``` (default: 1 em) plus the arrow length (about 3 em). So your lengths preserve the arrow length of 3 em (15 - 2*6).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use \qquad, use \hspace{}

Only define a "newcommand" if you are going to use it multiple times.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\schemestart \chemfig{A-B} \arrow \chemfig{A-B} \schemestop

\schemestart \chemfig{A-B} \hspace{2cm} \arrow \hspace{2cm} \chemfig{A-B} \schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image]